# Rxjs zip-like operator which returns only when observable fires in specific order

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Let's say I have two Observables A and B, and I want to combine them to produce this behaviour: the subscription combination returns only if A fires when a B has already been fired. It differs from the zip because I don't want any return if A has already been fired and then a B fires. In other words: ignores A until B fires then return on the next A, then ignore any other A until B fires ... so on

Comment: So you want to receive an array like this `[resultA, resultB]` where `resultA` will be `undefined` if `B` emits before `A`?

Comment: @martin not exactly, i tried to explain it better in ritaj's answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need `withLatestFrom` operator:

```
import { withLatestFrom, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

const obsA = interval(2000);
const obsB = interval(1000);
const resultingObs = obsB.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(obsA),
  map(([bValue, aValue]) => {
    return aValue
  })
);

// This should emit values from obsA only when obsB has been fired.
const subscribe = resultingObs .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: thats not exactly what i need, after the first time B fires after A the subscribtion returns everytime B fires. I need something which after B fires,it returns on the next A which fires,Let me try to put it in other words: I have a click event and a view which updates unregularly and the amount of things displayed changes: when i click i want to scroll to the bottom. if I click and the view did not update in time and new elements are shown, it will scroll but not to the bottom because new elements are shown after the click.(i.e view updates after click)

Comment: Hence to do it , i need to fire an Observable when clicked and one when the view has updated and combine them to know when i can scroll which is when the click observable is fired,then when the next view Observable is fired : scroll and ignore any view updates after that until another click